# From sample mean and variance of $X$ to $\sqrt{X}$

Tags: statistics, means

I have samples $x_i$ of lets say a random variable $X$ (euclidean distances, $X=\sqrt{Y}$, where $Y$ is the squared distance) which I computed from squared distances samples $y_i$.
I can now calculate the sample mean $\bar{x}$ and sample variance $s^2$ as:

$$ 
\bar{x} = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i   \\
s^2 = 1/(n-1) \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i- \bar{x})^2 
$$

as described here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_sample_covariance)

Is it possible to somehow compute the sample mean/variance for $Y$ (squared distances)
(more effiecient since no square root computation needs to be done)
and then transform it to the sample mean and sample variance of $X$ in an easy way?

Comment: The link mentions the variance of the sample mean, but not the sample variance.

Comment: jep, I corrected the question, thanks  :-)

Comment: Link gone now. Trying to guess what is going on. See possible Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid normal with mean $\mu$ and SD $\sigma,$
then $Z_1, \dots, Z_n,$ where $Z_i = (X_i - \mu)/\sigma,$ are iid *standard* normal (with zero mean and unit variance).

Finally, $Q = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_1^2$ has a chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, and $E(Q) = n$ and $V(Q) = 2n.$  Of course,
$Q$ is the squared distance from the origin in $n$-space, if each linear component is standard normal.

If this is on the right track for you, maybe look at Wikipedia on *chi-squared distribution.* Also the *Rayleigh* distribution has to do with the (Euclidean) distance between points in a plane.

Comment: Where did it say the distribution is normal?

Comment: Question unstable. Link (when present) not helpful. Context, purpose unclear. Took a stab at trying to help.See my Comment above. Notice my answer begins with "If...". If @Indominus has something useful to offer, why just a comment?